# Testing epistatis effect in R with small number of variants (SNPs)

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I am trying to test epistatis effects in a genetic dataset with about 50 snps (SNPs are coded as 0,1,2). Basically I want to test whether the SNPs have a positive or negative epistatis or just additive effect have on the disease status. So the formula that I want to test is:

```
disease ~ snp1 + snp2 + covariates
```

and also preferably later

```
disease ~ snp1 + snp2 + snp3 + covariates
disease ~ snp1 + snp2 + snp3 + snpn + covariates
```

But lets keep it simple in the beginning. The disease is coded on a 0 vs 1 way and the I have several other covariates including 10 PCA, age, gender and (categorical) sample origin... 
Does anyone know which function I should use in R to calculate the p-values for these tests?

Comment: Logarithmic regression using e.g. a logit link function? `glm(..., family = binomial(link = "logit"))` should get you started. As for testing the significance (and checking for collinearity) of predictors, that's when things get interesting... plenty of material available.